# jQuery ui dialog position chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, safari, dialog

i'm having some problems with jQuery UI dialog in Chrome and Safari. The dialog window popups in the middle of the screen as intended in FF and IE, but in Chrome and Safari the window centers itself according to the whole body. Not the current "viewframe" of the screen as with FF and IE.

I have tried to overcome this by adding an absolute/fixed div in which the dialog is contained, didn't work. And i tried to edit the .js file itself and change the appendTo: "body" without result. I've checked the dialog css file that .ui-dialog is positioned as absolute. Nothing has helped. Now i don't know what more to check without breaking it in FF and IE aswell.

I'm not experienced with javaScript/jQuery so that makes things even more tougher to sort this out.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#form").validationEngine('attach', {
        onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
            if (status == true) {
            $(function() {
                $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height:265,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    title: "Submit form",
                    buttons: {
                        "Submit": function() {
                            form.submit();
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                        "Cancel": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            }
        }  
    })
});
</script>
<div id="dialog-confirm">
    <p style="font-weight:bold;float:left;">Submit the form?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: "Any suggestions" Post relevant code or better a jsfiddle

Comment: @roasted: Thanks for your reply. Honstly i don't know what code to add since i don't know where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your dialog code to look like this:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:265,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                title: "Submit form",
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function() {
                        form.submit();
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                position: "center" // This part should address your issue.
            });
```